# How to plot with different palettes in subplots of the same figure?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

How can I plot with different palettes in subplots of the same figure? In the example below, the generation of the plots is delayed. So, only the last palette is used to generate plots. Though I need the subplots generated with a different palettes.

```
x = np.arange(10)
pal = sns.color_palette("rainbow", 12)
sns.set_palette(pal)

subplot(2, 1, 1)
for i in range(4):
    plot(x, i*np.sin(x))

subplot(2, 1, 2)

pal = sns.color_palette("Set1", 12)
sns.set_palette(pal)

for i in range(4):
    plot(x, i*np.cos(x))

tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the palette **before** creating the subplot. This is because the color cycle is a property of the axes. The axes will take the current property cycler from the `rcParams` at creation time. So `set_palette`, which changes the property cycler, needs to be called beforehand.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(10)

# First subplot
pal1 = sns.color_palette("rainbow", 12)
sns.set_palette(pal1)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
for i in range(4):
    plt.plot(x, i*np.sin(x))

# Second subplot
pal2 = sns.color_palette("Set1", 12)
sns.set_palette(pal2)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
for i in range(4):
    plt.plot(x, i*np.cos(x))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]